# Redis Database TTL

Tags: redis, ttl

Is there anyway to create a Redis database where keys **HAVE TO** expire after a certain time? I know I can expire an individual key using the `EXPIRE` command but since I am expiring every key after a certain time anyways, it would be nice to have this behavior specified in the Redis config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Redis (up to and including v3.2) does not provide the means for automatically setting the TTL of newly-created keys. You have to set it explicitly for each key you create.